# How to transfer Firefox passwords to Opera

Tags: firefox, passwords, opera, import, export

I'm trying to go from Firefox to Opera. I was able to transfer the bookmarks, but what about the saved passwords?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no good way to export passwords between most browsers (except between Firefox and Chrome, it seems).

My solution is to use a browser-independent password manager like [KeePass](http://keepass.info), [LastPass](http://lastpass.com), or [1Password](http://agilewebsolutions.com/products/1Password). That way, not only do your passwords remain free from browser data liberation problems, but your passwords are infinitely more secure too (there is no encryption on any browser's password manager except maybe Opera's, and Firefox's password manager has no encryption even with a master password, so it's interesting that they even have that option).

Answer (score 2):

FINALLY!!.....

Opera would not import Mozilla passwords despite the option (apparently). All my bookmarks were imported without issue.

Mozilla does encrypt/decrypt saved passwords using the Master Password. I removed my Master Password from Mozilla.

Tried importing passwords only from Mozilla.
Manage passwords were empty- even previously saved passwords from Opera were gone.

Shut down Opera, and restarted: Checked settings and....

Eureka!

all my Mozilla passwords were there.

However, I am considering using an independent password manager as a precaution.
It may seem silly, but I will print out all my passwords and keep the hard copy at home in a safe place. Sometimes primitive is more reliable.

Answer (score 0):

Opera has a import option to import all data - including passwords - from Firefox now.

Comment: It would be better if you'd explain which steps the user has to take to perform the import.

Comment: I have the latest opera and firefox. Opera fails to import passwords and bookmarks. It says "successfully imported" but did nothing.

Answer (score -1):

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) has an add-on for both browsers and offers an option for password syncing.

Comment: Um...no it doesn't.

Comment: Ah, frickin' opera. Right, no xmarks for Opera. My bad.

Comment: Hmm, nice trick. But, I probably wont trust XMarks encryption over standard techniques. The method can probably replicated with a stand alone mechanism that lets me encrypt the extracted password list and deliver it to the other browser to 'patch' it there. Would be very interested to know if someone has done this.